# ASP.NET core & C#. How to run a synchronous method asynchronously

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, io, openxml, c#-6.0

My ASP.NET core application uses Entity Framework Core. As you would expect must controller methods are async and call async methods of EF Core.

I also have controller methods thats need to read from and write to excel files. I'm using OpenXml. Since these are IO operation, ideally I they would be an async operation but OpenXml doesn't offer any async methods. Here is a simplified example

```
private async Task<model> ReadFromExcel()
{
    using var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("filePathAndName", false);

    // read data into model

    document.Close();

    context.Models.Add(newModel);
    await Context.SaveAsync();

    return newModel;
}
```

Also, I need to find the file in a folder first which I would also like to make async.

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles("excelFolderName", ".xlsx");
```

According to this document [ASP.NET Core Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-6.0) I shouldn't use Task.Run to make an synchronous API asynchronous. I understand why but does that rule apply to IO operations which will block the thread potential for a few seconds? Should I make these IO operations async and if so what is the base way to make reading and writing excel file and getting file list asynchronous?

Comment: ASP doesn't run actions on a UI thread and it sounds like you have to do stuff in order, so i think you should listen to the docs there...

Comment: what the doc tries to tell you is, that you won't benefit from methods that could be inlined as `await Task.Run(...);`, it would only cause useless scheduling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since these are IO operation, ideally I they would be an async operation but OpenXml doesn't offer any async methods.
>
> Also, I need to find the file in a folder first which I would also like to make async.

Ideally, those would be asynchronous APIs. But they're not. The way to *make* them asynchronous is to fix the API, not wrap it in `Task.Run`. You can open a request with the maintainers of OpenXml for asynchronous APIs. The file system operation is more awkward; it's a Win32 limitation, not a BCL limitation, and it's unlikely to be fixed, but you can ask.

> does that rule apply to IO operations which will block the thread potential for a few seconds?

Yes.

The *request* is blocked for the same amount of time whether it's synchronous or asynchronous. So the thing to consider is how *threads* are blocked. In the ideal asynchronous case, no threads are blocked. Since you only have synchronous APIs, you do have to block a thread; calling the API directly will block a thread pool thread, and shoving it off to `Task.Run` will block a different thread pool thread - which is pointless.

> Should I make these IO operations async and if so what is the base way to make reading and writing excel file and getting file list asynchronous?

You can't "make them async". You can request async APIs and then use the synchronous ones for now.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I figured but I had to ask.